# Continuity of the operator that takes a curve and gives its length

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

I have a sequence of Lipischitz continuous curves of finite length and with fixed endpoints $\{\gamma_n:[0,T]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $\gamma_n\rightarrow\gamma$. Denoted by $\mathcal{L}(\gamma)$ the length of the curve $\gamma$ can I say that $\mathcal{L}(\gamma_n)\rightarrow\mathcal{L}(\gamma)$? Convergence is taken with respect to the natural topology of the Bochner Sobolev space $W^{1,\infty}(0,T;\mathbb{R}^2)$.